# Let $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{{x}}$ and $g(x)=\tan x : |x|< \frac{\pi}{2}$ now find $D_{f \circ g}$?

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{{x}}$ and $g(x)=\tan x  : |x|< \dfrac{\pi}{2}$
now find $D_{f \circ g}$ ?

---

I know that $$D_{f \circ g}:\{ x\in D_g\mid g(x)\in D_f\}$$

$$D_f=-1\leq x< 0 \cup 0<x\leq1$$

$$D_g=|x|< \dfrac{\pi}{2}$$

Now what ?

Comment: $[-\pi/4,\pi/4]$ - {0}

Comment: @Ak19 .How is it proved?

Comment: As, $|x|<\pi/2$, $-\pi/2<x<\pi/2$ - for g = tan(x). Now, let y = tan(x). For f(y) to exist, we need $|y| = |tan(x)| < =1,$ y is not 0. And taking 4th and 1st quadrants,  - 1<= tan(x)< =1, except (0). So, we have $[-\pi/4,\pi/4]$ - {0} as the domain of $fog$

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$
f(g(x))=\frac{\sqrt{1-\tan^2x}}{\tan x}
$$
so you want that
\begin{cases}
1-\tan^2x\ge0 \\[4px]
\tan x\ne0
\end{cases}
The first inequality becomes $-1\le\tan x\le 1$.

Answer (score 1):

We need $g(x) \ne 0$ and $ g(x)^2 \le 1$.

That is we need $\tan x \ne 0$ and $\tan^2 (x) \le 1$

$$\tan x \in [-1,1]\setminus\{0\} \text{ and } |x| < \frac{\pi}2$$

Hence $$x \in \left[ -\frac{\pi}4, \frac{\pi}4\right] \setminus \{ 0\}$$